# Beamer - Color of header foreground with AnnArbor theme

Tags: beamer, header-footer, color

I use `beamer` with the theme `AnnArbor` and colortheme `whale`.

I tried to use:

```
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=blue}
```

or

```
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{fg=white, bg=blue}
```

But for an unknown reason, the `bg` works but not the `fg`... The sections names stay black in the header.

---

EDIT : the problem comes from the `hyperref` package.

This code works well :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white,bg=blue}

\begin{document}
    \section{Test 1}
    \subsection{Test 1.1}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Test}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Whereas this one doesn't works :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white,bg=blue}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=blue,
    citecolor=gray,
    frenchlinks=false,
    pdfborder={0 0 0}
}

\begin{document}
    \section{Test 1}
    \subsection{Test 1.1}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Test}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And that's pretty normal because of this line :

```
linkcolor=black,
```

Comment: Do you want to keep the yellow in the `AnnArbor` theme? Also, is the text actually black, or is it dark blue?

Comment: - I didn't keep the yellow by using :
`\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white,bg=softblue}`
(which works very well, even the `fg`)
- I don't know if it's black or dark blue but it doesn't have lots to see with my problem I think but thanks for your comment

Comment: This little test document `\documentclass{beamer} 
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=blue}

\begin{document}

\section{A test section}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}


\end{document}` gives the desired output (at least in my system), If it's not working for you, please edit your question and add a little, *complete* document (like the one I just gave) illustrating the problem.

Comment: Effectively... Shame on me to not tested it... By uncommenting little by little, I found the problem comes from hyperref.

Comment: `hyperref` is automatically loaded by `beamer`, so the problem might be caused by your `hypersetup` rather than by `hyperref`.

Comment: @erik --> I know : see the edit : the problem was the line `linkcolor=black,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved:

The problem was the following line in `hypersetup` which paint the sections title in black because they are link:

```
linkcolor=black,
```

Answer (score 3):

The `AnnArbor` theme is basically the following

```
\useinnertheme[shadow=true]{rounded}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usecolortheme{wolverine}
\setbeamerfont{block title}{size={}}
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure,bg=yellow!85!orange}
```

If the `AnnArbor` design and `whale` color scheme is what you're after, you could try putting this in your preamble instead of `\usetheme{AnnArbor}`.

```
\useinnertheme[shadow=true]{rounded}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usecolortheme{whale}
```

If you're just trying to change the headline colors, `\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{fg=white,bg=blue}` should change the right side of the headline, while `\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{fg=white,bg=blue}` should change the left side.