# Regarding the Beamer Theme

Tags: beamer, themes

Can anyone please tell which [beamer theme is used in the slides](http://fmwww.bc.edu/GStat/docs/StataIntro.pdf)?

[image]

Or, if there is no particular theme, then how to tweak the code so as to have this kind of theme?

The Modified MWE is:

```
\documentclass[serif]{beamer} 

\usepackage{hyperref}    
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, citecolor=blue, filecolor=blue, linkcolor=blue, urlcolor=blue}

\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.gif,.jpg,.eps}    
\usepackage{subfigure}    
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]    
\usetheme{AnnArbor}

\definecolor{darkred}{RGB}{104,0,4}
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{bg=darkred}   
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{fg=darkred!60!black,bg=yellow!85!orange}    
\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{fg=darkred!70!black,bg=yellow!60!orange}   
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=darkred, bg=yellow!60!orange }    
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\title{Are the Indian states fiscally sustainable?}
\author[Santosh Dash]{Santosh K. ~Dash \inst{1}}
\institute[] % (optional, but mostly needed)
{
  \inst{1}%
  JNU, New Delhi}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction and Motivation}
\begin{frame}{Introduction and Motivation}
 \begin{itemize}
  \item {Both States and Center.....} 
        \item Hence, we examine this issue. 
 \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

When i use that MWE, color of the title in the title page and section and sub-sections head appear in blue. I think it has to so something with hypersetup. I tried but i could not solve it. It should appear like the title page of the slide i referred to.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Have a look at this [Beamer theme gallery](http://deic.uab.es/~iblanes/beamer_gallery/index_by_theme.html). Seems to be the first one `AnnArbor`.

Comment: @dexteritas, Yes, it seems to be AnnArbor. But then its color combination is blue and yellow. How to have color combination red and yellow (like the slide linked above)? Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Start with a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and maybe have a look at [Beamer - Color of header foreground with AnnArbor theme](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208526/beamer-color-of-header-foreground-with-annarbor-theme) for color settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{AnnArbor}

\definecolor{darkred}{RGB}{104,0,4}

\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{bg=darkred}
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{fg=darkred!60!black,bg=yellow!85!orange}
\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{fg=darkred!70!black,bg=yellow!60!orange}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=darkred, bg=yellow!60!orange }
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\section{Theory}
 \begin{frame}{Theories}
 \begin{enumerate}
   \item Tax and spend hypothesis \pause
    \item Spend and tax hypothesis \pause
    \item Fiscal synchronization hypothesis \pause
    \item Institutional separation or fiscal neutrality hypothesis 
    \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In case you want to change the colour of more elements, have a look at http://www.cpt.univ-mrs.fr/~masson/latex/Beamer-appearance-cheat-sheet.pdf to get the respective names of the colours.

Comment: Dear @samcarter, I am grateful to for your help. That worked well. However, when i added the hyperefsetup in the preamble, the title and section colors appear in blue. I request you to kindly have a look at the revised MWE. I played around with the hypersetup...but i could not fix it.  Thank you a lot, samcarter.

Comment: @Santosh Either follow Zarkos suggestion on how to change the colour or disable the links, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183353/how-to-remove-link-from-title-in-foot

Comment: Thank you @samcarter. However, changing the colorlink to black makes the section title so dark that it is not visible. I want it to appear as you have already shown (the slide starting with "Theories"). Thank you a lot.

Comment: @Santosh Stupid question: if you don't like the colours of colorlinks, why are you explicitly use `\hypersetup` to enable colour links?

Answer (score 2):

- `beamer` load `hyperref` package, so you not need to do this again.
- blue color of title on title package have nothing with `hyperref` package, it is defined somewhere else:`\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{...}`.
- link in the foot is defined by `hyperref` set up.

for example, that you like to have like this:

[image]

then you need to change preamble of *mwe* provided by  [samcarter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter) as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, citecolor=blue, filecolor=blue, 
            linkcolor=black, % changed
            urlcolor=blue}

\usetheme{AnnArbor}

\definecolor{darkred}{RGB}{104,0,4}

\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{bg=darkred}
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{fg=darkred!60!black,bg=yellow!85!orange}
\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{fg=darkred!70!black,bg=yellow!60!orange}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=darkred, bg=yellow!60!orange }
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries}

\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure,fg=darkred, bg=yellow!85!orange}% added

\begin{document}
\title{Are the Indian states fiscally sustainable?}
\author[Santosh Dash]{Santosh K. ~Dash \inst{1}}
\institute[] % (optional, but mostly needed)
{
  \inst{1}%
  JNU, New Delhi}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Theory}
\begin{frame}{Theories}
    \begin{enumerate}
\item Tax and spend hypothesis \pause
\item Spend and tax hypothesis \pause
\item Fiscal synchronization hypothesis \pause
\item Institutional separation or fiscal neutrality hypothesis
    \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear @Zarko, I am grateful to you for your help. The MWE provided by you is fine. However, when i change linkcolor to linkcolor=black, starting from the second slide/frame, the section head is so black that it is not visible. My earnest request you to is that kindly create a new frame. For example, i want the second frame as shown by samcarter (kindly see below). You will see that the section head is not visible. Kindly help. Many thanks again.

Comment: @Santosh, don't change `hyperref` settings outside preamble. i add second frame and it is as expected. by the way, it is time to vote (and accept)   *samcarter* answer ... it solve your basic question.